# SQL Server Case Statement when IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do an IF statement type function in SQL server.

Where there is a NULL in the field, I want it to take a field from one of the tables and add 10 days to it.

And if possible create another column and add the 30 days.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    B.[ID],
    MAX(A.[START DATE]),
    B.[STAT],
    C.[POST DATE],
    CASE
          WHEN (C.[POST DATE] BETWEEN C.[EVENT DATE]+10 AND C.[EVENT DATE]+30) THEN 'GOOD'
          END AS [BETTER VISIT],
    CASE
          WHEN B.[STAT] IS NULL THEN (C.[EVENT DATE]+10)
          ELSE '-'
          END AS [DATE]
FROM 
    #TEMP1 A
    FULL OUTER JOIN #TEMP2 B
    ON A.[ID]=B.[ID]
    FULL OUTER JOIN #TEMP3 C
    ON A.[ID]=C.[ID]
GROUP BY
    B.[ID],
    B.[STAT],
    C.[POST DATE],
    C.[EVENT DATE]
ORDER BY
    A.[START DATE] DESC
```

The result would look sort of like:

```
    ID  START DATE   STAT    POST DATE    BETTER VISIT    DATE         DATE2
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   2013-01-01   GOOD    2013-11-01   GOOD            -            -
    2   2013-03-01   NULL    NULL         NULL            2013-03-11   2013-03-31
```

Comment: What's wrong with the output you're getting now?

Comment: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: IsNull might help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: I changed it to ISNULL and the error is now: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ISNULL'.

Answer (score 89):

```
CASE WHEN B.[STAT] IS NULL THEN (C.[EVENT DATE]+10)   -- Type DATETIME
     ELSE '-'                                         -- Type VARCHAR
     END AS [DATE]
```

You need to select one type or the other for the field, the field type can't vary by row.
The simplest is to remove the `ELSE '-'` and let it implicitly get the value `NULL` instead for the second case.

Comment: I tried this and the query runs but it returns a NULL instead of a value [EVENT DATE]+10 on the [STAT] fields that are NULL

Comment: @caffaddt Could you set up an SQLfiddle with some sample data? I only fixed the syntax of your query, I can't quite see the logic in your desired result without seeing some input data.

Comment: What I can tell you is that ID (char) is stored in a real table, so is EVENT DATE (datetime), STAT (varchar) is a column created by as CASE statement in another temp table, POST DATE is stored on a real table as well, and BETTER VISIT (varchar) is from the CASE statement in this table. Does that help a little? I'm fairly new to SQL so it will take me a while to build you the schemas on that site.

Comment: @caffaddt Set up a minimal test, I'm getting a date for the NULL stat. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80015/1

Comment: The data set looks exactly like how you have it with exception of the ID being char but that doesn't really matter to the set we're working with. I see that it does work on sqlfiddle so I don't know why it's not working in my query.

Comment: @caffaddt You could try changing the join to `#TEMP1 A
    FULL OUTER JOIN #TEMP2 B
    ON A.[ID]=B.[ID]
    FULL OUTER JOIN #TEMP3 C
    ON A.[ID]=C.[ID] OR B.[ID]=C.[ID]` Also verify that you have a row in B that has `STAT IS NULL` that has a row in `C` with the same `ID` and an non null `EVENT DATE`.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. Does it matter if I have "too many" temp tables before reaching to this final one? If yes, that might be the case.

Comment: @caffaddt Could you add a row (same ID in A, B, C) that you think should show up but doesn't to the SQLfiddle?

Comment: I ended up putting this table into another temp table and creating another query to query off of it  and the CASE statement worked. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 18):

I agree with Joachim that you should replace the hyphen with `NULL`.  But, if you really do want a hyphen, convert the date to a string:

```
(CASE WHEN B.[STAT] IS NULL
      THEN convert(varchar(10), C.[EVENT DATE]+10, 121)
      ELSE '-'
 END) AS [DATE]
```

Also, the `distinct` is unnecessary in your `select` statement.  The `group by` already does this for you.

Comment: This runs but doesn't return a value for DATE, it just gives everything a null.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `IIF` (I think from SQL Server 2012)

```
SELECT IIF(B.[STAT] IS NULL, C.[EVENT DATE]+10, '-') AS [DATE]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  case isnull(B.[stat],0)
  when 0 then dateadd(dd,10,(c.[Eventdate]))
  end
```

you can add in else statement if you want to add 30 days to the same .

Comment: I tried this and got this msg: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'STAT' to data type int.

Comment: you try the cast or convert function to change the data type to compare.

Answer (score 5):

In this situation you can use ISNULL() function instead of CASE expression

```
ISNULL(B.[STAT], C.[EVENT DATE]+10) AS [DATE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hyphen in your ELSE statement isn't accepted in the column which is being defined under the datetime data type. You could either:

a) Wrap a CAST around your [stat] field to convert it to a varchar representation of a date

b) Use a datetime like 9999-12-31 for your ELSE value.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on Mahesh solution for mssql:

```
case when isnull(B.[stat],0) = 0 
     then dateadd(dd,10,(c.[Eventdate]))  
end
```

Comment: Your welcome, please read help center and get tour for give best feedback.  https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ISNULL function. It helps you replace NULL values for other values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are answers here and this question is 10 years old.
I am aware that ISNULL is an alias for COALESCE and that tests should be in descending order of frequency, and that this breaks DRY.

COALESCE NULLS

```
CASE  COALESCE(B.[STAT],'-')
      WHEN '-' THEN '-'
      ELSE (C.[EVENT DATE]+10)
END AS [DATE]
```

There are other ways to code this, but this is readable and localised. Nesting is more complex.